# SymPy installation using pip3 not woking

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, sympy

I an on MacOS High Sierra and try to do some symbolic math using SymPi. I installed it using

```
pip install sympy
```

Now when I run the code

```
import sympy as sym
x= sym.Symbol('x')
print(sym.limit(sin(x)/x, x, 0))
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Symbol'
```

In fact the NameError occurs for many other constructors such as Rational(), etc. What is wrong please? I am in Microsoft VS code as IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the correct environment setup in VSC?  Are you using a Virtual Environment?  Doing what you have above works for me with OSX in a terminal & iPython.  Have you tried each line one at a time?

Comment: I am not using any environment in VSC.

Comment: One possibility is that you have a file called `sympy.py` and it is importing that instead of the installed SymPy module.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? That is to say, the entire message that gets printed, not just everything after `AttributeError`.

Comment: When working with Python I'd suggest creating a Virtual Environment.  That way you avoid clashing with python modules an python versions stored at the system level.  VSCode will also detect the Virtual Environment and ask if you want to use it.  Pretty handy.